# SLF4J debug​(String msg, Throwable t) lazy evaluation

Tags: java, slf4j

In SLF4J, parameterized messages are used to boost logging performance. For example, if you have the following:

```
logger.debug("The new entry is "+entry+".");
```

Entry will be evaluate whether or not you are in debug mode. However, by using parameterized, it will only be evaluated if you are in debug mode.

```
logger.debug("The new entry is {}.", entry);
```

My question is, is there a similar way for the exception logging to avoid redundant evaluation in non-debug mode?

```
debug​(String msg, Throwable t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is answered in slf4j faq [here](http://slf4j.org/faq.html#paramException)

As of SLF4J 1.6.0, parameterized logging is supported in error method provided that the exception object is the last parameter.

```
String s = "Hello world";
try {
  Integer i = Integer.valueOf(s);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  logger.error("Failed to format {}", s, e); // Notice only 1 pair of brackets. 
}
```